# How to make desired waveforms by AD5668?

Tags: dac

In another thread I asked about making sawtooth wave form via harmonics ( [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84391/how-to-make-sawtooth-wave-from-square-or-triangular-wave) ) and someone suggested using AD5668 (octal DAC ). I looked at its datasheet but couldn't understand how it can make a wave form. Can any one help me by making a suggestion/tutorial or something?

Comment: The octal DAC provides 8 channels for your sinusoidal harmonics by feeding in the appropriate digital values and timings to each channel. To make your sawtooth wave you need to **ADD together the sinusoidal waveforms** (with appropriate amplitudes) this can be done with an op amp (voltage adder) circuit **OR** you could could simply produce the sawtooth waveform by counting up and counting down and taking the output from one channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was the one who suggested the device to the OP in the other thread.

AD5668 is an Octal, 16-Bit SPI Voltage Output DAC with 5 ppm/°C On-Chip Reference. You need to select a sampling frequency first that is several times more than the frequency of the target signal. You can then just drive the DAC, using an SPI interface, with a pre-populated set of samples.

What I did, in order to generate an waveform, is that I wrote a general purpose function, that just adds the magnitude of respective harmonic components to the fundamental, along with phase information. This generates the array that is used to drive the DAC. The timer that is used to do the periodic SPI, is configured to control the fundamental frequency.

I just wrote some code to prototype the same. The function call to generate the array, for example, for a saw-tooth waveform is

```
GenSamplesHarmonics(20000,0,10000,180,6666,0,5000,180,4000,0,3333,180,2856,0,2500,180,2222,0,2000,180,1818,0,1666,180,1538,0,1428,180,1332,0);
```

I'll just try to explain:

A Saw-tooth wave is essentially all harmonics at amplitude 1/n, even harmonics negative. The fundamental amplitude is 20000(arbitrarily chosen). The next argument is the phase relationship with the fundamental(obviously zero in this case). Each subsequent argument pair is the 1/n of the fundamental, with each alternate pair 180 degrees out of phase.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Please let me know if I get it well: You put a fundamental voltage in the DAC and then use Fourier series to make next harmonics. This is what DDS devices do. I think this process is limited by the micro contoller's working frequency and I think this method is just available for lower frequencies ( for an AVR with 16MHz clock and 16 steps for each cycle this should not be able to make frequencies higher than 1 MHz). Do you use any sort of device that can work in higher frequencies? I need a 10MHz triangular wave.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. This is fundamentally limited to the microcontroller frequency, which is linked to the SPI frequency.

Comment: "For an AVR with 16MHz clock and 16 steps for each cycle this should not be able to make frequencies higher than 1 MHz", Not even that! You are doing SPI, with 24 clocks per division, and then the Nyquist limitation halves the available BW, so the frequency that you may generate would be a few kHz, not more than that.